# autocomplete multiselect field with results displayed in a div below

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, multi-select

I'm trying to create an autocomplete field with selected options displayed below the field with an option to remove them from the list. I was able to find code that allows me to do that with a dropdown list, but I can't figure out to get it to work with autocomplete.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bKWpg/1/

I also found this: http://jsfiddle.net/JhRL5/31/ and was thinking I could combine the two somehow, but I'm not sure how to begin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cities").change(function(){
        var a = $("#cities :selected").text();
        $("#selectedlist").html(a);
    });

});
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin that does exactly what I was looking for -- An multi-select autocomplete field that displays selected values in a div under it.

[image]

You can find it here with a more detailed explanation: https://github.com/punkave/jquery-selective

Answer (score 1):

I modified your first fiddle as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chosen-select-width").chosen({
    width: "75%"
  });
  $("#cities").change(function(e, chosen) {
    $a = $("<div/>", {
      text: chosen.selected
    }).append(
      $("<span/>", {
        text: "x",
        on: {
          click: function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
          }
        }
      })).appendTo("#selectedlist");
  });

});
```

```css
#selectedlist {
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 5px
}
#selectedlist div {
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin:0 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #ccc;
}
#selectedlist span {
  float: right;
  width: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  background: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<select data-placeholder="Start typing to select a city" multiple class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="16" id="cities">
  <option>Amsterdam</option>
  <option>Atlanta</option>
  <option>Calgary</option>
  <option>Chicago</option>
  <option>Denver</option>
  <option>Dubai</option>
  <option>Frankfurt</option>
  <option>Hong Kong</option>
  <option>Honolulu</option>
  <option>Houston</option>
  <option>Kuala Lumpur</option>
  <option>London</option>
  <option>Los Angeles</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<div id="selectedlist"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like the code works in the beginning, but then it gets a little weird when I try to add more cities. There's also a problem when removing cities from the select field (it duplicates the city instead). Do you know how I can **only** have the city appear in the div below and not in the select field?

Comment: The updated answer is definitely closer to what I want to do. I want it to be just like my first fiddle, but I want it to be autocomplete instead of a dropdown list.